# Not able to get promise result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

Here i am using [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/#validate-async) 
as a validator. I want return the result through promise, but i can't able get the result from the promise. Please can anybdy help me on this. here is my code.

```
const validate = require("validate.js"),
    Promise = require('bluebird');

var constraints = {
    "boarding": {
        "accesskey": {
            "presence": true
        },
        "secretKey": {
            "presence": true

        },
        "region": {
            "presence": true

        }
    }
};

let validator = {
    keyValidator: function (body) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            validate.async(body, constraints.boarding).then(function (success) {
              return  resolve(true);
            }, function (error) {
              return  reject(error);
            });
        })
    }
};

console.log("The Result is",validator.keyValidator({accesskey:"1233",secretKey:"sdfsdf",region:"south"}));
```

Comment: validator.keyValidator(..) returns a Promise object. You need to use its `then` method to get the value that you need.

Comment: @BidhanA i just started learning the Promises Could you p;ease Explain bit more

Comment: You can't just `console.log` the result from a Promise because it might take some time to execute. What you need to do is put your console.log() inside its `then` method. Something like this `validator.keyValidator(..).then(function(value) {console.log(value);});` . Read the docs on MDN.